# Unable to communicate between the docker containers from the same subnet after using CNI to assing IPs from azure vnet

Tags: azure, docker, azure-virtual-network

I was trying to give IP address to docker container from an azure vnet using the [CNI plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/container-networking-overview), I was successfully able to give IP address to containers but they were not communicating with each other.

I followed this [blog](https://medium.com/@rahul.metangale/connecting-docker-container-to-azure-virtual-network-ff8a19913574), which is based on this microsoft [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/deploy-container-networking#deploy-plug-in-for-docker-containers).

I created two containers using commands:

```
sudo ./docker-run.sh alpine1 default alpine
```

and

```
sudo ./docker-run.sh alpine2 default alpine
```

I checked that the IP of alpine1 is `10.10.3.59` and IP of alpine2 is `10.10.3.61` which are the IPs I created inside a network interface as given in the above docs. So they did receive the IPs from a subnet inside vnet but when I ping alpine1 from alpine2 as `ping 10.10.3.59`, it doesn't work, am I missing something here ? Or I have to do some other configuration after this ?

Comment: ping is not the best way to test connectivity. try creating a nginx container and expose port 80 and try curling that from the other container.

Comment: but if both containers are in same subnet, they should be able to ping each other right ?

Comment: not necessary, i dont know how it works, it might not handle icmp

Comment: I am able to ping both of the container from the Primary IP `10.10.3.15` of my network interface

Comment: icmp requests are not blocked internally on an azure vnet.

Comment: doesnt mean this cni plugin supports icmp

Comment: after enabling IP Forwarding on the azure vm, I am able to communicate between the containers.